# How to exclude null relations in Laravel eloquent eager loading?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

I'am using Laravel Eloquent to query MySQL database. I have a table `base_node` and related table `base_data` (OneToOne relation). `base_data`.`node_id` = `base_node`.`id`. Query is the following

```
$result = BaseNode::with(['data' => function ($query) use ($filter_text) {

    $query->where('head', 'like', '%'. $filter_text. '%');

}])->get()->toJSon();
```

Query result `[{'id': 1, ..., 'data': {'id': 1, ...}}, {'id': 2, ..., 'data': null}]`.

As you can see, if `base_data`.`head` is not match by filter condition, `data` field in result is null. How can I construct eloquent query to exclude such rows from result completely. For example, desired result is `[{'id': 1, ..., 'data': {'id': 1, ...}}]`.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `with("data")->whereHas([ "data"=> function ($query) use ($filter_text) ... ])`

Comment: @apokryfos Thank you! It's work.

Answer (score -1):

According to @apokryfos answer, in Laravel 5.8 `whereHas()` had another syntax:

```php
with("data")->whereHas([ "data", function ($query) use ($filter_text) ... ])
```

Comment: Not working for me. I'm trying to exclude my parent `Application` model if my morphTo of my `modelable` relationship is null. I've got this issue open here -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76330876/laravel-querying-morph-relationship-returns-null-and-parent-model-still-exists where I've tried whereHas