# Laravel querying morph relationship returns null and parent model still exists?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I'm working in Laravel 10. I have a `Application` model with a `modelable` relationship.

```php
/**
 * Get the parent modelable model.
 */
public function modelable()
{
    return $this->morphTo();
}
```

I need to query a column on the morphed relationship, and exclude `Application` if `modelable` is null. What am I missing from my query below to achieve this since `modelable` is returned as null if no records are found and the parent application is still there. I need to exclude it.

```php
$applications = Application::query();
$applications = $applications->where('submitted_at', '>=', Carbon::parse($request->input('from')))
                                ->where('submitted_at', '<=', Carbon::parse($request->input('to')));

$applications = $applications->where('company_id', $company->id);

if ($company->is_default) {
    $applications = $applications->orWhereNull('company_id');
}

if ($request->input('affiliates')) {
    $applications->whereIn('affiliate_id', $request->input('affiliates'));
}

if ($request->input('campaigns')) {
    $applications->whereIn('campaign_id', $request->input('campaigns'));
}

$applications = $applications->with([
    'redirect',
    'campaign',
    'affiliate'
])->withWhereHas('modelable', function ($query) use ($request) {
    if ($request->input('firstName')) {
        $query->where('AppFirstName', $request->input('firstName'));
    }
    if ($request->input('lastName')) {
        $query->where('AppLastName', $request->input('lastName'));
    }
    if ($request->input('email')) {
        $query->where('AppEmail', $request->input('email'));
    }
    if ($request->input('phone')) {
        $query->where('AppMobilePhone', $request->input('phone'));
    }
})

$applications = $applications->orderBy('submitted_at', 'desc')
                                ->paginate($request->input('perPage', 10));

$applications = $applications->onEachSide(1);

if (! $applications || count($applications) <= 0) {
    return new ApiSuccessResponse(null, [
        'message' => 'No applications found.',
    ], 404);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The contains() method determines if a given key exist in the collection. You can also provide the value to check against the key as a second argument, which will check if the given key/value pair exists in the collection. You can use the contains() method on collections which contains arrays and objects as well.

Comment: Okay, but I want to exclude applications where the nested relationship is null. How do I achieve this?